# Find a point on the surface $f=2 x^{2}-y^{2}-4 x+z^{2}=10$ where its tangent plane is parallel to the plane $P=2 y+4 z=3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces

Find a point on the surface $f=2 x^{2}-y^{2}-4 x+z^{2}=10$ where its tangent plane is parallel to the plane $P=2 y+4 z=3$

I did the gradient of f

$[4x-4,-2y,2z]$

and gradient of P

$[0,2,4]$

and then I did

$4x-4=0\\-2y=2t\\2z=4t$

and Im stuck here
$x=1, y=-t, z=2t$

and then I put that values on $f$ and resolve for $t$

and I get $t=-2,2$

and from here I don't know what to do, or Im doing bad things?

Comment: You are almost done. The points are $(x,y,z)=(1,-t,2t)$ with $t=2$ or $t=-2$. [There are two points].

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Oh then $[1,-2,4]$ and $[1,2,-4]$ are the points rights?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.